# How can I present a ViewController from a touch point?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

Is there any way to present a ViewController from a touch point or selected cell in a tableView or collectionView(which is in scrollView)?

Now I'm using a `UIView` to mimic presentation animation, but this is not the correct way to solve this problem and also make the code dirty. I can't compound `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` with the touched point. I tried Hero Transitions but they use a custom class for collectionView and not really helpful for my project.

I will be very appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You should use Custom presentation process.

It is well described in [ViewController Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningCustomPresentations.html)

Basically you should do using the following steps:

1. Create custom animator objects for presenting and dismissing your `ViewController`
2. Adopt `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`

Nice tutorial on subject at [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/359-ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions)

Comment: :/ In that tutorial, they used a custom class for collectionView, they did their own collectionView which is inherited from scrollView. In our project, I can't do that. But this helps someone else, thank you.

Comment: It's not necessary to subclass the CollectionView. All you need to show `UIViewController` by tapping on it  is an initial `frame` of it. It doesn't matter how you retrieve it. I have a simple [reference project](https://github.com/fewlinesofcode/InteractiveTransition/tree/master). It might be easier to understand.